# Get motor ratings from unknown DC motors

Tags: motor, dc-motor, measurement, ratings

I've purchased bulk cheap DC motors for a robot problem. But I don't know their ratings.

Is there a way for me to find out?

For instance, I would like to know their max DC voltage input using basic tool like a multimeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motors are rated by manufacturers based on the class of insulation they have.  Different insulation classes have different allowable maximum temperatures (or, alternatively, temperature rises over 40 C ambient temperature).  A standard method of measuring temperature rise in an DC motor armature is to measure resistance at room temperature, then load the motor and allow it to run until steady state temperature has been reached.  Then you measure the resistance again and from that you can calculate temperature rise of the armature.  The load which causes your maximum allowable temperature rise is your rated speed, torque, power, etc.  This would normally be done on a dynamometer and the speed, torque, input voltage and current, power, efficiency, etc. would be measured and/or calculated.  I am guessing that your motors have Class B insulation, which allow for a 90 C temp rise over ambient temperature.

Maximum voltage for low voltage DC motors would probably be set based on maximum allowable speed.  Max speed is a function of a lot of things including type of bearings, size of your armature, and how well your winding is secured (especially around the commutator).

The voltage constant can be measured by back-driving a motor with another motor.  Then just measure the speed the motor is turning at and measure the voltage being generated on the leads.  Divide the voltage by the speed and you get Ke.

Answer (score 2):

A multimeter won't tell you this and realistically nothing will other than either the maker's details (not available) or trial and error. Trial and error means testing each one and finding out how much torque and speed it can generate and how hot it might get. You need to make an estimate of how hot you dare run the motor and hope for the best.

I hope someone can help you more than I can. A typical smallish DC motor rated for 12V will have a measured dc resistance of possibly 1 or 2 ohms when not turning. At 24V this might be between 5 ohms and 10 ohms so no real coherent measurement on resistance will work.